# postgresql: how to delete database cluster

Tags: postgresql

I have used the command initdb to create a database cluster:

```
sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/initdb -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/defaultdb'
```

If I want to delete this database cluster, can I simply remove the folder defaultdb? Or is there some command I should use?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, If you want to delete the database cluster you just created just remove the data directory `/opt/local/var/db/postgresql83/defaultdb`.

By the way, if the PG server is running, shut it down before.

Comment: Thanks, if I had enough reputations, I would vote up this answer :)

Comment: If you are recreating the same cluster again, you need to wait few minutes until `pg_lsclusters` doesn't show the old cluster

Answer (score 63):

If you are using something debian-like, the cleanest way is to run [pg_dropcluster](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/cgi-bin/manServer.pl/usr/share/man/man8/pg_dropcluster.8)

```
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.4 main
```

Comment: Usually a cluster which still has a running server attached will not be deleted. To override this, the --stop option forces a server shutdown before the files are removed.

Comment: As is implied by this answer's opening line: `pg_dropcluster` is only available on debian and maybe rhel-like systems, i.e. despite having beginning with `pg_` it is not included by default in the postgresql packaging and must be separately installed.